# i am using ajax functionality for pdf downloading on button click, but its not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

My Code Snippet:

```
function printWithMultiTecords() {
     $selectedRowsIds = $this->input->post('selectedRowsIds');
     //getting record ids in above array
        if(!empty($selectedRowsIds))
        { 
         for($i=0;$i<count($selectedRowsIds);$i++)
         { 
       $select  = 'ci_order.*';
          $where  = array('order_no'=>$selectedRowsIds[$i]);
          $this->db->order_by('ci_order.order_id DESC');

          $this->data['details'][$i]  =  $this -> admin -> getDataFromTableWithWhere('ci_order',$where,$select);

              }
           $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
           $html = $this->load->view('orders/print_order', $this->data, true);
           // print_r($html); die;
           pdf_create($html, 'orderreceipt');

            echo "1";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "0";
  } 
    }
```

PDF CREATE FUNCTION:

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
 {
  require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  if ($stream) {
   $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
  } else {
   return $dompdf->output();
  }
 }
```

I am using above functions on ajax call to download pdf..

everything is working fine.. but only pdf create is not working there (means pdf not getting generated)

There is no any kind of error..

please suggest the changes in above code??

Comment: you cannot o/p file from ajax because of security policy

Comment: Instead of ajax use page redirect and set header to download file

Comment: Make sure your directory (where file is to be generated is writable) and In Ajax Click while downloading   | Generate the file on server, return the  link as response and open link a new tab  (by javascript) and file will start downloading(close the new tab).